# PHP loop over csv - start and end loop at Regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, loops, csv

I need to print out csv file into html or put a numeric data into database:
But I need to start a loop at specific position and break it at another specific position (regex).
So I need to reprint only rows with numerical data and all columns from them.
Following is pseudo-code - not working properly:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
$handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))
{
   if (preg_match('/[Morning]/', $data[0]) === 1 // start at this rwo plus two lines down )
    {
    $num = count($data);
    $row++;
      for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++)
      {
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++)
            {  
              echo $data[$c] . " ";
            }   
      if (preg_match('/[Total Cash:]/', $data[0]) === 1)
        { break; row -1 }            
      }
       echo "<br>";  
   }
}
fclose($handle); ?>
```

So csv goes like this:

```
/--some lines--/
```

Date: 3/3/11,
Morning,
--blank line---
Customer No,Time,CheckNo,Total,
1234,12-45,01,20.00,
1236,1-00,03,30.00,
1240,2-00,06,30.00,
--more numerical rows of data at variable length that I need to loop over--
1500,4-00,07,22.00, 
----,----,---,----,
Total Cash, , , ,120.00,

/*--some other lines--and it goes*/

Lunch Time,
---similar like Morning above ---

Any info how to properly addrres this issue is appreciated, I can now do so many loops and regex but with this I need some more time and help. Thanks.

Comment: Not your typical CSV file, ey?

Comment: `/[Morning]/`? You are looking for a value, that contains `M`, `o`, `r`, ..., _or_ `g`?

Comment: Yes - it should be just 'Morning'..

Comment: @Brad: No, data is not consistent - I'm not sure if mysql 'load data infile' would work to parse Morning data, Lunch data etc - see edit in csv sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lines = file('test.csv'); //read file into an array, one entry per line

$active = false; //keep track of what rows to parse

//loop one line at a time
for ($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
  $line = $lines[$i];

  if (strpos($line, 'Morning') !== false) { //start parsing on the next row
    $active = true;
    $i += 2; //skip the blank line and header
    continue;
  }
  if (strpos($line, '----,') !== false) { //stop parsing rows
    $active = false;
  }

  if ($active) { //if parsing enabled, split the line on commas and do something with the values
    $values = str_getcsv(trim($line));
    foreach ($values as $value) {
      echo $value . " "; //these are the numbers
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = file('test.csv');
$parsing = false;
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $parsing = ((strpos($line, 'Morning') !== false) || $parsing)
        && ((strpos($line, 'Total Cash') === false);

    if (!$parsing)
        continue;

    $values = strgetcsv($line);
    echo implode(' ', $values);
}
```

Edit: Basically, it does the same as Dan Grossmans solution, but shorter ;-)

Comment: You should not use `explode()` for parsing CSV-data, because `firstvalue,"second,value"` will not recognized correctly.

Comment: I just realized that and edited your solution in. Much better and cleaner that way.

Comment: @Grossman: Read it here first, thus its just bad luck ;) But right; assuming, that the values are all numeric (with `.` as decimal separator), allows to use `explode()` here. My bad

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = file('test.csv');

// Skip the unwanted lines
// Means: Every line until the line containing "Morning,"
do {
    $line = array_shift($lines);
} while(trim($line) !== 'Morning,');
$lines = array_slice($lines, 2); // Mentioned something about "2 lines below" or such" ^^

// Do something with the remaining lines, until
// Line _begins_ with "Total Cash"
while(strncmp('Total Cash', trim($line = array_shift($lines)), 10) !== 0) {
    echo implode(' ', str_getcsv($line)) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Note: This will only work, if you have only '''one''' sequence of lines to parse. If later in the document you have a second passage you want to parse, this won't capture it

Comment: This looks like a bill or something, so one can assume, that there is no other passage to parse. On the other hand its quite simple: Wrap the whole stuff in `do { /* see code in answer */ } while (!empty($lines));`

Comment: Of course - it wasn't to criticize your answer, just a note ;)